# iOS App rejected iTunes 17.2 clause

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've recently had an app rejected due to the 17.2 clause

> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

My app requires users to create a user account before they are able to use the app. All data in the app is tied to a specific user. Rather then create a custom login, it seemed simple enough to get users to signup with Facebook for "one-click" account creation instead of having to fill out a new account form. So I used the Facebook Graph SDK for iOS to accomplish this. However, I did not use any other features from the Facebook SDK and as a result of doing so, my app was rejected. I have a couple of uncertainties I was hoping could be answered.

**Can I just implement a custom create account without the risk of getting my app rejected?**  The custom create account will require fields such as a userName, email, and account passWord.

**I read somewhere that in order for Apple to approve custom account creation, the app must have some sort of Privacy Policy. Is this true?**

**What would classify as a "significant" use of Facebook services to justify the use of Facebook authentication? Would using features such as Share to Facebook and Invite Friends be significant enough to use in the app to get approved?**

I'm curious to know how others have solved this problem and any advice or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: In your Application what is  the information you share ?

Comment: As of now no information is shared. The facebook profile information is stored and tied to that user. However this is the public profile information and it does not contain sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is **very** annoying with this clause. It isn't about how you are using the Facebook SDK, it is about asking users to create an account via any means. You have to justify your features so that they are user-oriented. You can bend the world in your favor on how you do this, though.

For example, even though a feature seems to be completely okay if user doesn't register, you can argue, "for better user experiences, we calculate user's performance on these features, and associate it with the account."

Or, you can go about saying "although this seem to be not user-related, we use the gender information to serve correct content."

Privacy policy is a must. You definitely need that accessible through the app and through the App Store page.

While working to get our app accepted after it got rejected by the same clause, my team spent a whole day trying to relate every major feature to something such that an account was necessary. But the good news is, it got accepted!

On another note, Facebook friend invites are fine, but making users upload a profile picture and create their own contents also need to be explained. They will ask questions such as "who will be able to see these contents?"

It is a tedious process, but more of a, "provide information and I'll let you pass" kind of thing. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your information, do you think I would need a Privacy Policy regardless of if I used Facebook Account or had users create a custom account?

Comment: Indeed, because either way you are obtaining user information, so you need to inform users what you are going to do with it.